# Как отобрать из строки нужную часть в python?

Tags: python, строки, поиск

Есть строка где N-e количество повторяется такая структура:

```
"{'v': '375_0', 'n': 'last_frame'}, {'v': 'Название_чего_либо_0', 'n': 'title'}"
```

(375_0 и Название_чего_либо_0 - это условно)

Как получить из всей строки список вида: "Название_чего_либо_0, 375; Название_чего_либо_1, 375_1; Название_чего_либо_2, 375_2; и т.д."

Comment: формализуйте вопрос - откуда известно, что именно должен содержать итоговый список.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: В строку выгружается перечень клипов и куча мета данных, таких как: название клима (title), его продолжительность (last_frame) и других мне не нужных. Итоговый список должен содержать перечень наименований клипов и продолжительность. В структурах выше они указаны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = "{'v': '375_0', 'n': 'last_frame'}, {'v': 'Название_чего_либо_0', 'n': 'title'}, " \
       "{'v': '375_1', 'n': 'last_frame'}, {'v': 'Название_чего_либо_1', 'n': 'title'}, " \
       "{'v': '375_2', 'n': 'last_frame'}, {'v': 'Название_чего_либо_2', 'n': 'title'}"
dictionaries = eval(data)  # из строки делаем кортеж словарей
my_string = ''
ind_a, ind_b = 0, 1
while ind_b < len(dictionaries):
    my_string = my_string+dictionaries[ind_b]['v']+', '+dictionaries[ind_a]['v']+'; '
    ind_a, ind_b = ind_a + 2, ind_b + 2
my_string = my_string[:-2]  # Убираем ; после последнего элемента
print(my_string)
```

Код для создания тестовой строки с 2500 пар:

```
import random
import string


data = []
for i in range(2500):
    number = f'{random.randint(100, 2500)}_{random.randint(0, 9)}'
    some_str1 = random.randint(5, 11)*random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    some_str2 = random.randint(5, 11)*random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
    some_title = random.randint(5, 11)*random.choice('абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя')
    data.append(f"{{'v': '{number}', 'n': '{some_str1}'}}, {{'v': '{some_title}', 'n': '{some_str2}'}}, ")
data = ''.join(data)
print(data)
```

Или если у вас много разных параметров - хорошо подойдет использование регулярных выражений. Например, выражение, захватывающее то, что в last_frame и title: https://regex101.com/r/0dRGBP/1

Тогда код:

```
import re


data = 'Здесь пишете свою строку или приравниваете data к переменной со строкой'
data = re.findall(r"'v'([^{]+?)', 'n': 'last_frame'}, {'v':([^{]+?)', 'n': 'title", data)
data = str(data)
data = data[1:-1]  # удаляем []
data = re.sub('"', '', data)
data = data.replace("(: '", '')
data = re.sub(",  '", ',', data)
data = data.replace(', ', ';')  # меняем , между парами на ; и убираем пробел
data = data.replace(')', '')
data = data.split(';')
new_data = [i.split(',')[::-1] for i in data]
data_str = '; '.join([', '.join(i) for i in new_data])
print(data_str)
```

Вывод (по вашим данным):

день металлурга 2020_1, 92524; RABOCHI_9, 2277; RABOCHI_8, 2087; RABOCHI_7, 2173; RABOCHI_6, 2774; RABOCHI_29, 2262; RABOCHI_5, 2029; RABOCHI_3, 3165; RABOCHI_4, 2567; RABOCHI_28, 2003; RABOCHI_26, 2322; RABOCHI_27, 2211; RABOCHI_25, 2437; RABOCHI_24, 2650; RABOCHI_23, 2570; RABOCHI_22, 2226; RABOCHI_21, 2758; RABOCHI_20, 2849; RABOCHI_2, 2500; RABOCHI_18, 2366; RABOCHI_19, 2202; RABOCHI_17, 2477; RABOCHI_16, 1969; RABOCHI_15, 2462; RABOCHI_14, 2342; RABOCHI_12, 2370; RABOCHI_13, 2209; RABOCHI_11, 2140; RABOCHI_10, 2299; RABOCHI_1, 3123

Comment: "{'v': '375_0', 'n': 'last_frame'}, {'v': 'Название_чего_либо_0', 'n': 'title'}" это часть строки где много мусора. и эти записи повторяются в этом мусоре через некий интервал.

Comment: В строке 2.5 миллиона символов, если убрать пробелы то будет 2.25 млн. Таких пар в этой строке около 2500.

Comment: Этот код работает и для 2500 пар, если строка и мусор в ней имеют тот формат, который вы указали в вопросе. Код забирает то, что через : после 'v' в каждой паре, а то, что после 'n' он не трогает. Приведите пример вашей строки (хотя бы часть из 10 пар) и то, что вам из неё нужно

Comment: Не знаю, какой длинны можно показать пример. Из 1150 символов можно тут как то организовать? "{'v': '375_0', 'n': 'last_frame'}, {'v': 'Название_чего_либо_0', 'n': 'title'}" не идут друг за другом, извиняюсь если ввел в заблуждение я просто их перечислил.

Comment: Можно на внешний сервис залить, а сюда отправить ссылку. Например, https://codeshare.io/

Comment: взял папку поменьше: https://codeshare.io/VZwyo3

Comment: Тогда используйте регулярные выражения. Я отредактировал ответ, если это вам поможет - нажмите принять ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! это то что нужно.